# How to start a timer when a call is get connected?

Tags: java, android, call, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I need to start a timer when a call get connected, but in my case it is starting when call is ringing, I searched a lot, but did't get proper solution. With the hope again I'm repeating this. At least i need a suggestion to achieve this.

My code:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {    
        Log.d("Status", "Phone is Ringing");
    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {    
        Log.d("Status", "Phone is on call");
    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
        // Call Dropped or rejected   

        System.exit(0);
        Log.d("Status", "Phone is dropped");
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out.
Inside your BroadCastReceiver

```
static boolean flag = false;
static long start_time, end_time;
```

And the onReceive function will be something like this,

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
            if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                end_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                //Total time talked =
                long total_time = end_time - start_time;
                //Store total_time somewhere or pass it to an Activity using intent
            }
        }
```

Also you need to giver permissions for this in the Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Register a receiver in your Manifest like this :

```
 <receiver android:name=".CallDurationReceiver">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
       </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Timer means i need start a new activity, there i am starting timer.

Comment: Which activity are you starting?

Comment: my prob is i need to start my simple app that to when user received a cal. There i am starting the timer. Here my activity starting When Outgoing cal ringing only

Comment: So i need exact state when user receive